# ERROR could not access file "$libdir/repmgr_funcs" No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, repmgr

I follow this [link](https://edwardsamuel.wordpress.com/2016/04/28/set-up-postgresql-9-5-master-slave-replication-using-repmgr/) to create master slave replication on Ubuntu postgresql server.

My Configuration of `repmgr` and `postgresql` are:

Postgresql 9.5-: `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.5/`

repmgr-: `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/repmgr`

repmgr.conf -: `/etc/rep.conf`

```
pg_config --pkglibdir => /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib


ls /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib | grep repmgr_funcs => repmgr_funcs.so
```

I am getting ERROR-: unable to create the function

```
repmgr_update_last_updated: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/repmgr_funcs": No such file or directory

ERROR: Unable to create repmgr schema - see preceding error message(s); aborting
```

Comment: Did lib install in correct place? `$ pg_config --pkglibdir` =>
`/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/lib` then
`$ ls /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/lib | grep repmgr_funcs` =>
`repmgr_funcs.so`

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I update the question please check..thanks for your response

Comment: You could give absolute path to where library is located (in function body), something like `AS '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/repmgr_funcs'`. But it shouldn't really matter if you already have it in $libdir. Maybe for some reason postgres doesn't have access to its $libdir. I can't come up with any good answer sadly.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Thanks for your response so i add path to libdir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `repmgr` ver. 4 and above then you need to change in `postgresql.conf`
From `shared_preload_libraries = 'repmgr_funcs'`
To `shared_preload_libraries = 'repmgr'`

Below are their upgrade notes

> The repmgr shared library has been renamed from repmgr_funcs to
>   repmgr, meaning shared_preload_libraries in postgresql.conf needs to
>   be updated to the new name: shared_preload_libraries = 'repmgr'